# Udemy API HTTP Authorization

Tags: javascript, api, http, authorization, superagent

Hi I'm Learning API and I want to do a project with the the API of Udemy. Reading the documentation I see these example

```
curl --user {YOUR_CLIENT_ID}:{YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET} https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses
curl -H "Authorization: Basic {BASE64_ENCODED(CLIENT_ID:CLIENT_SECRET)}" https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses
```

But I don't know how to translate that into my code using superagent , right know I have this

```
const request = superagent
request.get("https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses")
.set({myClientId}, {myClient_Secret})
.then(function(serverResult){
console.log(serverResult)})
```

But still appear in console 
GET https://www.udemy.com/api-2.0/courses 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not a valid problem statement.  Provide an error message, or some other clue as to how we would proceed.

Comment: Thanks, I already update my question

Answer (score 0):

In case this is helpful, this is a basic function that calls the Udemy Instructor API from Google Apps Script (GAS). GAS provides the UrlFetchApp().fetch() method. This is proprietary to Apps Script, but you still may find the structure of the header helpful.

```js
function callUdemyInstructorAPI () {
  var baseUrl = 'https://www.udemy.com/instructor-api/v1/';
  var url = baseUrl + 'taught-courses/courses/?apiOptionsHere';
  var params = {
  "method" : "GET",
     "headers" : {
       'Authorization' : 'bearer mySecretUdemyAPIToken',
     }
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
}
```